# Plotting residuals for non-linear models created with bbmle package

Tags: r

i'm trying to get the residual plots for a non-linear model i built with bbmle, but have no idea how to approach this task. The bble package has some notes on residuals but no way of plotting something like a histogram. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The residuals() function seems to work.  And you can then do whatever you want - histogram, qqplot, scatterplot of residuals against predicted values (predict() also has a method).  For example:

```
set.seed(1002)
lymax <- c(0,2)
lhalf <- 0
x <- runif(200)
g <- factor(rep(c("a","b"),each=100))
y <- rnbinom(200,mu=exp(lymax[g])/(1+x/exp(lhalf)),size=2)
dat <- data.frame(y,g,x)

fit3 <- mle2(y~dnbinom(mu=exp(lymax)/(1+x/exp(lhalf)),size=exp(logk)),
    parameters=list(lymax~g),
    start=list(lymax=0,lhalf=0,logk=0),
    data=dat)


par(mfrow=c(2,2))
hist(residuals(fit3))
qqnorm(residuals(fit3))
hist(residuals(fit3, type="response"))
qqnorm(residuals(fit3, type="response"))
```

[image]

Or have I missed the point?

Comment: Thanks Peter. This was exactly what I was hoping to do for my models